# What would be the most efficient way to do this search (mysql or text)?

Tags: python, mysql, database, regex, search

Suppose I have 500 rows of data, each with a paragraph of text (like this paragraph). That's it.I want to do a search that matches part of words. (%LIKE%, not FULL_TEXT)

What would be faster?

1. SELECT * FROM ...WHERE LIKE "%query%"; This would put load on the database server.
2. Select all. Then, go through each one and do **.find >= 0** This would put load on the web server.

This is a website, and people will be searching frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very hard for us to determine without knowing:

- the amount of text to search
- the load and configuration on the database server
- the load and configuration on on the webserver
- etc etc ...

With that said i would **conceptually** definitely go for the first scenario. It should be lightening-fast when searching only 500 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a full text search if you use myisam engine. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-query-expansion.html